# Change Default Hover Data for hvplot.hist

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot

I have the following dataframe called `df` that contains 2 columns:

```py
In [4]: df.head(20)                                                                               
Out[4]: 
     age age_band
0    NaN      NaN
1   61.0    55-64
2    NaN      NaN
3   55.0    55-64
4    NaN      NaN
5   67.0      65+
6    NaN      NaN
7   20.0    18-24
8   53.0    45-54
9    NaN      NaN
10   NaN      NaN
11  23.0    18-24
12  60.0    55-64
13   NaN      NaN
14  54.0    45-54
15   NaN      NaN
16  67.0      65+
17   NaN      NaN
18  50.0    45-54
19  70.0      65+
```

```py
In [5]: df.info()                                                                                 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 107632 entries, 0 to 107631
Data columns (total 2 columns):
age         73289 non-null float64
age_band    73289 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.6+ MB
```

```py
In [7]: df["age_band"].value_counts()                                                             
Out[7]: 
45-54    22461
55-64    17048
35-44    14582
65+      12990
25-34     4078
18-24     2130
Name: age_band, dtype: int64
```

```py
In [8]: df["age"].min()                                                                           
Out[8]: 19.0

In [9]: df["age"].max()                                                                           
Out[9]: 74.0
```

**AIM:**
I want to plot a histogram for `df["age"]` using hvplot. In this plot, I would like to place the ages into bins that correspond with my `df["age_band"]` column values. The following plot does this:

```py
In [10]: df.hvplot.hist("age",bins=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],xticks=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],hover_cols
    ...: =["age_band"],line_width=4,line_color="w")
```

[image]

When you hover over each bin, the count for each `age_band` correctly displays as `Count`, however, rather than each `age band` value, it seems to display the mean or median `age` for each bin.

Upon further investigation, it appears that setting `hover_cols="age_band"` actually had no effect on the plot (you get an identical plot if it is omitted.)

I then tried to use HoverTool:

```py
In [11]: from bokeh.models import HoverTool 
    ...:      
    ...: hover = HoverTool(tooltips=df["age_band"].dropna()) 
    ...:  
    ...: df.hvplot.hist("age",bins=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],xticks=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],line_width
    ...: =4,line_color="w").opts(tools=[hover])
```

However I got the following error:

```py
ValueError: expected an element of either String or List(Tuple(String, String)), got 1         55-64
```

So then I tried:

```py
In [12]: from bokeh.models import HoverTool 
    ...:      
    ...: hover = HoverTool(tooltips="age_band") 
    ...:  
    ...: df.hvplot.hist("age",bins=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],xticks=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],line_wi
    ...: dth=4,line_color="w").opts(tools=[hover])
```

Which resulted in:

[image]

So then I also tried:

```py
In [13]: hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("18-24","2130"),("25-34","4078"),("35-44","14582"),("45-54",
    ...: "22461"),("55-64","17048"),("65+","12990")]) 
    ...:  
    ...: df.hvplot.hist("age",bins=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],xticks=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],line_width
    ...: =4,line_color="w").opts(tools=[hover])
```

Which resulted in the following:

[image]

Is there a way to produce a histogram of `df["age"]`, using hvplot.hist, where when you hover over a bin then you are presented with the corresponding `age_band` & `Count` of `age_band`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting **by=['age_band']** should work and should show you that column when you hover:

```
df.hvplot.hist(
    y='age',
    by=['age_band'],
    legend=False,
    color='lightblue',
    bins=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],
    xticks=[18,25,35,45,55,65,74],
)
```

Although in the case you describe you could also choose to **create a barplot on the value_counts**:

```
age_band_counts = df['age_band'].value_counts().sort_index()

age_band_counts.hvplot.bar(bar_width=1.0)
```